# How to assign multiple numbers to multiple letters in one word?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import string
values = dict()
user_entry=raw_input("Enter: ")
for index, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase):
    values[letter] = index + 1

print values[user_entry]
```

I am trying to get a number for each letter from a word the user enters. For example, if the user enters "code" then I need to assign a number to c, o, d, and e. For c it would be 3, for o it would be 15, for d it would be 4, and for e it would be 5. I tried to separate them by using list so that I can split each letter to get a number for each letter but nothing seems to work. I need some help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was this what you were looking for:

```
import string

values = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)}

user_entry=raw_input("Enter: ")

print([values[i] for i in user_entry])
#[3, 15, 4, 5]
```

And another way would be:

```
import string

low = string.ascii_lowercase

user_entry=raw_input("Enter: ")

print([low.index(i)+1 for i in user_entry])
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for but is there any other way to do it? Just wanted to know. Thank you!!!

Comment: Or `map(values.get, user_entry)`. @Joey, no I don't think there is a *better* way.

Comment: @jpp or without `list()`, it's Python 2.x :)

Comment: what does v:k do in here?

Comment: @Joey Inverts the dict from `1: 'a'` to `'a':1`

Comment: @Joey Added example without `dict`

Comment: What is the purpose of i here I've never understood it. Why doesn't it also says that i is undefined?

Comment: @Joey That pattern is called [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Comment: Last question I promise. Can I get an answer in an integer form not a list?

Comment: @Joey Like a string `'31545'`?

Comment: like this: 3 15 4 5

Comment: and i still want to use that answer in my further program

Comment: so that's why i was asking

Comment: @Joey Wouldn't `list` be better? Because `3 15 4 5` is not an integer.

Comment: let's say I have a list of xyz=["q","w","e","r","t","y"] and what I need to do is find the 3rd letter in the xyz list then the 15th letter and so on depending on what the user inputs.

Comment: please help zipa!!

Comment: Well this code does it, you can maybe propose another question with more details and I'll be glad to help you